# What unramified Galois representations come from geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, motives

I think we don't know what crystalline representations come from geometry. What about the unramified ones? Specifically let $\phi:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)\to GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ be a continuous unramified representation. When is $\phi$ a subquotient of $H^{i}_{{\acute{\mathrm{e}}\text {t}}}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}, \mathbb{Q}_p(j))$ where $X$ is a smooth proper $\mathbb{Q}_p$-scheme?

Comment: My understanding is it should be only the ones with finite image, but I don't have a good references.

Comment: Can't we get an infinite image unramified character as a sub of the Galois rep on $H^1$ of an elliptic curve with good ordinary reduction? Perhaps we could similarly get from abelian varieties any semi-simple unframified representation in which Frobenius with eigenvalues that are Weil numbers (at least if we allow extending the coefficients).

Comment: @SashaP Good point, I was thinking about representations of the Galois group of a number field, not local ones. Your construction gives every Weil integer of weight $1$ that is a $p$-adic unit, hence every product or ratio of such. Perhaps one can obtain all Weil numbers that are $p$-adic units this way.